# Switch State not changing setChecked has no effect

Tags: android

I am working on an App with MQTT Client, on Message Receive I want to change the state of a Switch.

On MQTT messageArrived I have tried to do `swLED.setChecked(true);` But its not working Has no effect, I mean nothing is changed and also

> I don't see next line Log.i(TAG, "DONE"); was executed

and I don't see any exception. Wonder what's happening there!?

> swLED.getText() showing the Text of Switch that means swLED is okay
>   here
>   But still swLED.setChecked(true); has no effect

```
void processMessage(String msg) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Changing Switch Status to ON: "+swLED.getText());
    swLED.setChecked(true);
    Log.i(TAG, "DONE");
}

  //THIS METHOD IS MQTT CLIENT CALL BACK METHOD On Message Recceive  
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
    String Message =  new String(mqttMessage.getPayload());
    Log.i(TAG, "messageArrived Topic:" + topic + " Message: " + Message);
    processMessage(Message);
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch swLED = null;
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener switchListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "SWITCH ONNNNNN");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "SWITCH OFFFFFF");
                }
            }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swLED = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.swLED);
        swLED.setOnCheckedChangeListener(switchListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ischecked.question in not that much clear

Comment: @ManiTeja  swLED.setChecked(true); has no effect when I call it from a MQTT Client messageArrived callback method

Comment: isChecked is boolean value.. we will get this value public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) callback

Comment: calling swLED.setChecked(true); from anyother function will change the Switch state and display. you can call it from any where I tried it using from a button handler and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make changes to UI elements you need to use the [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

All attempts to update on other threads will throw exceptions which is why you are not seeing the log code run

Comment: It worked with runOnUiThread, Thanks for the help. Learned a new thing Today